# Using Identity Server for Customized Login Screens with business logic

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, security, duende-identity-server

I’m currently in the process of developing a new application using ASP.NET and React, with plans to host it on Azure. The application’s unique feature involves generating individual login screens based on specific business cases. Each generated link will provide users with access to their dedicated login screen, where they can also view business-specific content associated with that link.

My primary concern revolves around the utilization of OpenID Connect (OIDC), particularly Identity Server, to ensure these customized login screens. The challenge is that each login screen needs to be tailored to unique link and its related business logic. Furthermore, the business data resides within a separate microservice, which adds complexity to how Identity Server can access this data.

Additionally, since the login process will be contained within the single domain and won’t involve third party authentication, I’m questioning whether Identity Server is the optimal choice for this scenario. If it is, I’d greatly appreciate guidance on how to effectively implement it to achieve the desired functionality. If not, I’m open to suggestions on the best approach to accomplish this type of logging mechanism correctly.

Looking forward to your thoughts and suggestions!